# Why is is this a Java file if I am programming in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am your classic programmer that learned in Java for app dev and is now trying to switch over to Kotlin. Right now I am just going through the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#kotlin) that Android Developer has. On that page though I come across this.

```
fun sendMessage(view: View) {
    //What you do in response to click

    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
    val message = editText.text.toString()
    val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

On line 6 the code references a Java file. Is this supposed to be there for anything?

I know the extension for Kotlin files is .kt so why isn't that attached?

Comment: Based on the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) Kotlin classes are different from Java classes, and since `Intent` requires a Java class, that's one way to do it.  I'm not a kt dev, so maybe someone else can correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::class.java` is requesting the Java class, as they can be used inside Kotlin files. Although it ends in `.java`, it is just a reference to a Java class, not a file.

See:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#java-reflection

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @alxgmpr's answer, [`::class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references) operator returns a `KClass`, which is a reference to a Kotlin class. It is conceptually similar to Java's `Class` type, but it is technically different, as it needs to provide Kotlin-specific capabilities (e.g., `isSealed`, `isCompanion`).

So `KClass != Class`.

However, `Intent` is written in Java and knows nothing about `KClass` (but it knows about `Class`), that's why you need to use [`KClass.java`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html), which returns the Java class corresponding to that specific `KClass`.

Here's an example that should clarify that (types are explicit to differentiate the 2 variables):

```
val kClass: kotlin.reflect.KClass<String> = String::class
val javaClass: java.lang.Class<String> = kClass.java // equivalent to String::class.java
```